# initial commit failed android studio. cannot read

Tags: git, android-studio, github

I tried to share a project from android studio to github.
But it says " Successfully created project 'xyz' on GitHub, but initial push failed: Could not read from remote repository ". What do i do?

Answer (score 4):

Go to ,
File -> Settings -> Version Control -> Git -> SSH executable: Native 
and 
File -> Settings -> Version Control -> Github -> uncheck "Clone git repositories using ssh"

Its solved my problem.

Answer (score 1):

This could be a bug on IntelliJ IDEA's part. Try going to File -> Settings -> Version Control -> Git -> SSH executable: Native (if it was already set on native then switch between Built-in and then back to Native)

Now try pushing the commit remotely. Let me know if that works.